# How can I view the creation date (and creator) of a child site (not an admin person)

Tags: properties, topology, 2007

Is there any way an end user (with contribute or full access) can view the properties of A CHILD SITE...as in when it was created and by whom?

Answer (score 2):

My [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) can help with this, using the Webs Web Service, GetWeb method.